# Станик - це бюстгальтер чи безрукавка?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%96%D1%84) пише:

> «**Ліфчик**» — розмовна назва бюстгальтера. В Україні також називався стан, стано́к, **ста́ник**.

У [Всесвітньому словнику української мови](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) читаю:

> **станик** - **безрукавка, кофта** та ін.

Отже, ***станик - це бюстгальтер чи безрукавка***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/stanyk) знаходимо:

> **СТА́НИК**, а, чол.
>   1. заст. Верхня частина сукні від плечей до пояса (без рукавів). Сукня з коротким стаником; 
>   //  Верхня частина жіночої сорочки (до підтички); 
>   //  Ліф кофти; 
>   //  Кофта. 
>    2. діал. Безрукавка.

У [Словнику лемківської говірки](https://storinka-m.kiev.ua/article.php?id=1299) знаходимо:

> **станик**
>   -ника, ч. Пт.
>   Ліфчик, корсет.

У [Словнику львівської говірки](https://storinka-m.kiev.ua/article.php?id=1299):

> **стани́к** - бюстгальтер

Отже, це слово має 2 значення.